# php why do i allways get a 1 on date

Tags: php, date, time

so this is weird i dont understand why i am getting this but anyway

my code is

```
$checkTime = "00:00";
echo 'Check Time : '.date('H:i', $checkTime);
echo "<br>";
```

the value allways gets output as Check Time : 00:01 say i increment the mins value it then increaments the hour value.

But if i increment the hour value it then increments the minute value...

anyway my main issue is with the value set at 00:00, it outputs 00:01 and i dont understand why it does this, and if i increment the value it increments by one each time.

Can anyone help me understand why its doing this?

Comment: Read the manual! `date()` needs a timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Second parameter of date function should be in Unix Time Stamp format.

Comment: Thanks, sorry it was a silly issue its been a long day today :( i dont think the heatwave here is helping either lol.